# Set progress on ProgressBar in another class

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-fragments, progress-bar, android-tabs

I've got a `MainActivity` which has two tabs on `ActionBar`. My main layout on that activity is an empty `FrameLayout`. The first tab contains a `ProgressBar`, the second has `Button` that starts downloading files. Here's `SettingsTab`:

```
public class SettingsTab extends Fragment {
    private Button downloadButton;
    private ImagesTab imagesTab;
    private static String fileDir = "sdcard/AndroidCourse/";
    public void downloadImages(String url,int limit,String imageExtension)
    {

        try {
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .detectAll()
            .build());
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("img[src$=.");
            sb.append(imageExtension);
            sb.append("]");
            Elements images = doc.select(sb.toString());
            ArrayList<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(Element image : images) {
                if(urls.size() == limit) {  
                    break;
                }
                urls.add(image.attr("src"));
            }
            Log.e("urls", String.valueOf(urls.size()));
            imagesTab.downloadStarted(urls);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("SettingsTab", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_tab, null);
        downloadButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        imagesTab = new ImagesTab();
        downloadButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                downloadImages("http://www.google.com",5,"jpg");


            }

        });
        return view;

    }
}
```

and `ImagesTab`:

```
public class ImagesTab extends Fragment {
    ProgressBar downloadProgressBar;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.images_tab, null);
        downloadProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.downloadProgressBar);
        //downloadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        return view;

    }
    public void downloadStarted(ArrayList<String> urls)
    {
        //downloadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DownloadService.class);
        intent.putExtra("urls", urls);
        intent.putExtra("receiver", new DownloadReceiver(new Handler()));
        getActivity().startService(intent);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Service started!" + urls.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    private class DownloadReceiver extends ResultReceiver{
        public DownloadReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
            if (resultCode == DownloadService.UPDATE_PROGRESS) {
                int progress = resultData.getInt("progress");
                downloadProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
                if (progress == 100) {
                    downloadProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the *StartDownload* `Button`, the application crashes with the following exception:

```
11-26 03:55:55.765: E/AndroidRuntime(21200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 03:55:55.765: E/AndroidRuntime(21200): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 03:55:55.765: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
11-26 03:55:55.765: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3227)
11-26 03:55:55.765: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at com.example.lista2.ImagesTab.downloadStarted(ImagesTab.java:32)
11-26 03:55:55.765: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at com.example.lista2.SettingsTab.downloadImages(SettingsTab.java:55)
11-26 03:55:55.765: E/AndroidRuntime(21200):    at com.example.lista2.SettingsTab$1.onClick(SettingsTab.java:72)
```

Does anyone have an idea how to change the progress of a `ProgressBar` in on different part of app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your code, and the reason for that `NullPointerException` is the line:

```
imagesTab = new ImagesTab();
```

where you instantiate a new `ImagesTab` `Fragment`. The problem is this new `Fragment` instance isn't tied to an `Activity`(it's in the "air") so its `getActivity()` method returns `null`. This `null` value from the `getActivity()` method you pass to the `Intent` that you build in the `downloadStarted()` method which will throw the `NulPointerException`. Instead of instantiating the `ImgesTab` like you do, you should get a reference to the other fragment which is already(most likely) in the parent activity by using the `getFragmentManager()` and searching for the fragment based on its tag.

Second, updating the `ProgressBar` seems more of a app design problem. For example, why do you have the `Button` that starts the download in a tab and the `ProgressBar` which shows the download progress in another tab? Also, you seem to use a `Service` for the download, so instead of making the tabs communicating you should really make the `Service` that downloads the files and the desired tab fragment(with the `ProgressBar`) communicate. This could be made very simple by making the `Service` to a send broadcast at certain download levels and making your `Activity`(which holds the two tabs fragments) dynamically registering a `BroadcastReceiver`. When the `Service` sends a broadcast(for example at 10%), the `Activity`'s `BroadcastReceiver` will pick it up(if it's alive) and then it will update the `ProgressBar` from the desired `Fragment` if that `Fragment` is visible at that moment.